# sed to replace strings with special characters

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace particular strings from a text file

Input:
Computer Peripherals
Internet Technology
C/C++

Output :
Shopping
Generic
Programming

When i try using the follwing sed:

```
refcat="Computer Peripherals"
cat1="Shopping"
echo $list | sed -e 's@$refcat@$cat1@g'
```

I get the following result:

Computer
Peripherals
Internet
Technology

I get the output on a different line. Can someone pls help me with this?? My Input and Output values can have special characters in them ( Except '|' or '@' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the shell to expand variables, you need double quotes I think

```
echo $list | sed -e "s@$refcat@$cat1@g"
```

my example

```
echo Computer Peripherals Internet Technology C/C++ | sed -e "s@${refcat}@${cat1}@g"
```

result

```
Shopping Internet Technology C/C++
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out there was a problem while i was reading my input from the file. I fixed that and used your suggestion of the double quotes. Now it's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes don't interpolate shell variables, so change to double quotes:

```
echo $list | sed -e "s@$refcat@$cat1@g"
```